# Deleting lines from file not matching pattern with sed

Tags: sed

I generate a list of everything in a directory (subdirectories and all files) with

```
ls -R $DIRPATH | awk '/:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0} /:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=1;next} NF&&f{ print s"/"$0 }' > filelist
```

and I would like to delete all files not ending in a certain file extension, for example `.h`. I am trying this with

```
sed -ne '/.h$/p' filelist > filelist_h
```

but this is allowing files like `C:/dev/boost/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph`. How do I get this working with `.h` and not `h`?

Comment: `.` means any char in regex.  You need to escape to mean literal `.`.  However `find` is what you should be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` is the tool you are looking for:

```
find "$DIRPATH" -type f -name '*.h'
```